# Clang compatibility with XCode 4.4.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, clang, static-analysis

I am using XCode 4.4.1 and want to do static analysis via CLang manually.

I downloaded Clang checker build 267.

Using xcodebuild I am able to build my project, but when using scan-build xcodebuild, I get error.

```
Details: Unable to get message category info for tool '/Users/vinay/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer'.
Reason: Can't execute "clang": No such file or directory at line /Users/vinay/checker-267/libexec/ccc-analyzer 428
```

Can I use Clang with XCode version 4.4  Or is there any other static analysis tool that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clang's static analyzer is available from within Xcode: Use Product→Analyze, or hit shift-cmd-b to use it on your project.